# Capistrano deploy through chain of servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I need to deploy a Rails application via capistrano to a server on a remote intranet. For example, if I were to ssh into the target server it would look like:

```
localhost$ ssh server1
server1$ ssh server2
```

Whats the best way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capistrano makes this really easy.  Just use

```
set :gateway, "user@server1:port"
```

in your config/deploy.rb.

Comment: Seeing as this is the selected answer, it could be updated with the current way of doing it. See Dienow's answer below for details.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, gateway option was dropped from capistrano starting v3. Instead one can use a jump proxy as shown here: https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#proxying

Here's how it's going to look in the configuration file (e.g. production.rb):

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/ssh/proxy/jump'


set :ssh_options, {
    proxy: Net::SSH::Proxy::Jump.new("user@host:port")
}
```

BTW, you can specify jump proxy with -J option of the ssh command, so you can debug the connection issues separately from capistrano.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using:

```
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
set :gateway, "user@host:port"
```